# How can I change params in url with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want change the url in my angularjs app on the fly by tipping in a inputfield.

e.g.

1. I stay on:
   `http://localhost/test/year/2012`
2. I will change on the side via a input field the year to 2013 that call my yearIsChanged function, than the url should changed to
   `http://localhost/test/year/2013`
3. But with my current configuration the url is changed to 
   `http://localhost/test/year/2012/?year=2013`

My modul configuration.

```
var module = angular.module('exampleApp').
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/test/year/:year', {templateUrl: 'partials/test.html', controller: OverviewCtrl, reloadOnSearch: false}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

Controller action:

```
 function OverviewCtrl($scope,$routeParams, $location) {
      $scope.yearIsChanged = function () {
        $location.search('year', $scope.year);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`$location.search` will create an url like:

```
http://localhost/test/year/2012?year=2013
```

which is not what you want. You need to use `$location.url()`:

```
function OverviewCtrl($scope,$routeParams, $location) {
      $scope.yearIsChanged = function () {
        $location.url('/test/year/' + $scope.year);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Ok, that change my url correctly. But with `$location.url(...)` is the page reloading and the "`reloadOnSearch`: false" param is not working. Has AngularJS another param for e.g. `reloadOnUrlChange`?

Comment: Your OverviewCtrl will be executed again when the route actually changes (e.g. not when you enter '2012')

Comment: If I enter something in my inputfield, then the controller is reinitialized and I lost the focus of my inputfield. It is a problem because I can not focus the inputfield for every character. :D

Comment: Can't you trigger it on blur? or on change, but not on keypress?

Comment: I have changed my inputfield to a select. I have always the same problem that the focus is lost, but I can live with it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

Actually if you'll use 'search' then $location service will change 'search' part of URL, see [URL spec](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt). So AngularJS will detect that routing would not be changed and has possibility not to reload controller (`reloadOnSearch:false`).

But using .url or .path methods can change whole URLs, but AngularJS router can't detect can it re-use controller or not. So the only option is apply routing table to new url and re-initialize routes.

To achieve your goal (specific urls like /year/2012) without re-loading controller, you can:

1. rewrite ngView directive (and possible some changes to default routing in AngularJS) and try to re-use scopes. This sounds like quite havy change.
2. Don't use default AngularJS routing and implement desired behaviour by yourself.

Here is [**sample Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dzcM4pKbk7Y28i3pKNXL?p=preview) that illustrates second option (press small blue button in preview pane to see how URL changes, and also check that prev/next browser's buttons do not reload page/controller).

Answer (score 5):

You should notice that in your route :

"when (' / test / year / **: year** ' "

the **BOLD** word , is a **routeParam** and  **is not** search fileds.

So if you want to change your route , you should use this :

```
    function OverviewCtrl($scope,$routeParams, $location) {
      $scope.yearIsChanged = function () {
       $location.path('/test/year/'+$scope.year)
     // .path() will set(or get) your routeParams 
     // .search() will set(or get) your seach fields like your error
     }   
   }
```