# How to use Angular $location to set my new url location by changing its key-value params dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a RESTful endpoint that accepts a range of facets to query data. Here's a few examples:

```
example.com/search?type=Doctor&location=Boston,MA&radius=2  
example.com/search?type=Facility&location=Wayne,NJ&radius=3&gender=f  
example.com/search?type=Doctor&location=Patterson,NJ
```

My module accepts the query object to perform the search:

```
console.log(query);
{
  type:'Doctor',
  location:'Boston,MA',
  radius:'2'
}

$scope.getSearch = function(query){
  var search = $search.search(query);
  search.getResults(function(results){
    $scope.results = results;
  });
}
```

These facets are being passed through a local model in a web form:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="query.location"/>
 <input type="text" ng-model="query.radius"/>
 <button type="button" ng-click="getSearch(query)">Search</button>
```

In the success callback of the `getResults` function, I'm trying to append the query parameters to the URL like in the examples above:

```
$scope.getSearch = function(query){
  var search = $search.search(query);
  search.getResults(function(results){
    $scope.results = results;
    search.appendQueryToURL(query);
  });
}
```

How do I append URL parameters dynamically in AngularJS?

Comment: are you looking for $location.search()?

Comment: @KhanhTO Holy... yes. It even accepts key value pairs.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Using $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

```
$location.path('/newValue').search({key: value});
```

**For Non AngularJS applications:**

You can use history.js to append parameters dynamically to the url.
then split the url to retrieve the params and pass to angular:

```
History.replaceState({state:1}, "State 1", "?Param1=something");
```

I am suggesting history.js as IE until ver9 didnt support history object push state, if you are going to use IE10+ or google chrome, use the history state object to update the url.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: There's really no native AngularJS method that does this for you already?

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location
reflecting this in my answer .
Please upvote if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Havent used it alot but please follow this, this might give you a better idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174394/how-can-i-change-params-in-url-with-angularjs

Comment: A nice interface for touching the url; I was a bit disappointed that it requires a hash (possibly only if the url ends with a `/`), but what can ya do.

Comment: Chaining the path and search this way will cause the existing parameters to be replaced. The op's question is to append. Hence, append the parameter using $location.search(key, paramValue) and then call $location.path(yourPath).

Answer (score 1):

For the example above, the path() of your $location would be

```
'/search'
```

and the root is

```
'http://example.com'
```

Going back to his question, he did not ask to update the location with new path, he asked to update the location with new key-value pairs query dynamically!

So to do that, it's just everyday jQuery $x(newX)!

```
$location.search({type: x, location: y, radius: z});
```

or

```
$location.search({type: x, location: y});
```

It's all jQuery !!

If he wants to change the path from search to something else, he can do:

```
$location.path('/otherPath'); 
//his new location would be 'example.com/otherPath'
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, instead of using $location to call your data-service endpoint, a normal way to do that is

```
<form id='searchForm' ng-submit="getDataService()" ng-controller="aController">
<input ng-model="type"/>
<input ng-model="location"/>
<input ng-model="radius"/>
<input ng-model="gender"/>
<button type='submit'/>
</form>
```

and in getDataService() do a

```
$http.get( serviceUrl, config ).success( ...
```

with your serviceUrl being

```
example.com/search/Facility/Wayne,NJ/3/f
```

after parsing (using sprintf)